# Attempt to backup a list of folders that some are git repositories

Tags: rsync, backup

I have a list of folders that soime of them are git repositories. In order to backup it I tried thje following `rsync` command:

```
LANG=EN_us.UTF-8 rsync -ravdhHP --delete --files-from=rsyncFolders.txt --ignore="node_modules" --ignore="vendor" --include .git --exclude-from="$(if [ `git ls-tree -d --name-only master SRC | wc -l` -eq 1 ]; then git -C SRC ls-files --exclude-standard -oi --directory > .git/ignores.tmp && echo .git/ignores.tmp; fi)" --exclude node_modules --exclude vendor . "/media/pcmagas/79B56D48414DEE1B/pcmagas"
```

I have a lift of folders to backup on a file named `rsyncFolders.txt` and has the following content:

```
folder_a
folder_b
somefile_txt
code
```

In the `code` folder there exists some `.git` repositories and in that there is lots of `junk` files and folders in order I want to avoid keeping it into my backup. So the logic for my backup is the following:

1. If folder is a `.git` repo do nto keep a `.gitignore`d files
2. If not then ignore any `*.class` files in case that there are some java files. (Some sample code snippets that have been toyed around)
3. Any case do not backup any `node_modules` or `vendor` folcers in case of a php or a javascript project.

The above command when I run it I get the following error:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
rsync: --ignore=node_modules: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1572) [client=3.1.1]
```

Do you know how to do that?